# The inverse of a between select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select the inverse of a data range in a Postgres database:
the query i am trying to use is

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects 
WHERE lastactivity BETWEEN 2015-08-3 AND 2015-09-11
```

Comment: WHERE NOT lastactivity BETWEEN ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT` operator in your `BETWEEN` condition like

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects 
WHERE lastactivity NOT BETWEEN '2015-08-03' AND '2015-09-11';
```